# Schrodinger's Contacts in Lync

Tags: lync-2013

Often times I find that many (sometimes, it seems all) of my contacts will appear as offline or away, and therefore automatically left in the "Away and Offline Contacts" section, until I actually view the user in the contact list. When I expand the "Away and Offline Contacts" section, and as I scroll through it, the users' status icon will initially be grey. But then, very quickly after a user is shown in the list, their status will update and users who are actually online will turn green and be automatically moved to the appropriate group.

Occasionally, though it seems less often, the reverse will also occur - when I scroll past a bunch of online contacts, a lot of them will suddenly switch to offline/away at once.

This occurs with Lync 2013 on both my work computer and my home computer, both using the same account and servers. So, I'm not sure if this is a server-side issue or a client-side issue, or a little of both.

What can cause this? Are there things that and end-user can do to troubleshoot and fix this, or does it require Lync/Exchange Administrator assistance as well?

Comment: This is [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your admin.

Comment: @SvW Perhaps better suited for [su]? If it's a problem that doesn't require admin intervention (and I don't know that it is/isn't for sure - this is one of the reasons I'm asking), I don't see why it wouldn't belong either there or here. Either way, an answer of "this is a problem that needs to be resolved on the server or requires admin intervention" is also perfectly acceptable, if true.

Comment: I am sure of one thing: It doesn't belong here because *you* are not the admin of the Lync server and can't do anything if admin intervention is required. Other than that, I've never even seen Lync in action, so I don't know anything about it and can't tell if this might be a question for [SU]. Why don't you just talk to your admin?

Comment: @SvW That process is mired in corporate procedure involving a call center and several tiers of support. I much prefer to self-support troubleshooting of issues when I can - it's usually faster and less painful (and often more educational) that way.

Comment: Rather than beat the questioner over the head with downvotes, why don't we just vote to close-and-move this to SuperUser, where it belongs?  It's reasonably worded as questions go - and certainly better than the usual "my intarwebz broke, halp" stuff that we get.

Comment: @Iszi did you ever get this resolved? I have exactly the same problem

Comment: @lethalMango Nope. Even after the change to "Skype for Business", or whatever Microsoft likes to call it, I still have this issue.